# Automation of TSM Maintenance Cleanup command in Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a file that will help me to automate the `"tsm maintenance cleanup"` command everyday on `Tableau Server` at specific time. `Tableau` is installed in "D" drive and I'm facing some login issues due to temp files in D drive.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

VERSION 2019.2 USING .BAT file

A "call" statement is required as a prefix to each command in the scheduled .bat file of TSM commands (was not required when using tabadmin commands in v10). This apparently ensures control is retained by and returned to the calling .bat file i.e the scheduled log-files cleanup .bat,rather than control passing to the TSM batch.

so .bat file invoking TSM for weekly cleanup is

```
call tsm login -u <Username> -p <Password>
call tsm stop
call tsm maintenance cleanup -l --log-files-retention 14
call tsm start
call tsm logout
```

this example just clears logs (-l switch) but you can use other switches as appropriate to clear image cache, temp files etc. see the details at https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/cli_maintenance_tsm.htm#cleanup

We run it out of hours as it stops and restarts the server.